# Hide/Suppress equations by only changing preamble?

Tags: math-mode, equations, environments

Is it possible to change the preamble to hide/suppress equations?

**Consider the MWE below. This prints:**

[image]

By changing the preamble I want to hide the whole equation, and print a placeholder (in non math mode) with the number (optional), however references are still looked up correctly, so:

**Desired by changing preamble only:**

[image]

**Minimal Working Example**

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Our formula:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = 2x
\label{math:f1}
\end{equation}
See equation \ref{math:f1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{environ}
\RenewEnviron{equation}{%
\setbox0\vbox{%
$$\refstepcounter{equation}%
\let\zz\write
\def\write{\immediate\zz}%
\BODY$$}%
\par
\textbf{equation \theequation\ suppressed}%
\par}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Our formula:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = 2x
\label{math:f1}
\end{equation}
See equation \ref{math:f1}
\end{document}
```

this supports `\ref` (`\pagref` would be a bit harder)

Comment: I guess that the problem with `\pageref`, which makes is "harder", arises because your environment  hijacks the `\write` command with the consequence that `\thepage` does not get expanded in the aux file?

Comment: @Andrew yes could make `\thepage` be expanded but I do an \immediate\write so it doesn't get stuck in the box, which means the page number would be wrong even if thepage expanded

Answer (score 2):

The following captures the `\label` inside `equation` and allows you to activate/deactivate the use equation suppression:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{environ}
\let\oldequation\equation
\let\endoldequation\endequation
\let\ltxlabel\label

\newsavebox{\storebox}
\newcommand{\suppressequations}{%
  \RenewEnviron{equation}{%
    \let\storedlabel\relax
    \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\gdef\storedlabel{####1}}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\storebox}
      $\BODY$
    \end{lrbox}%
    \par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}
    \noindent
    \refstepcounter{equation}\ifx\storedlabel\relax\else
      \ltxlabel{\storedlabel}%
    \fi
    \textbf{Equation~(\theequation) is suppressed}
    \par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\restoreequations}{%
  \let\equation\oldequation
  \let\endequation\endoldequation}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\suppressequations
Our formula:
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = 2x \label{math:f1}
\end{equation}
See equation \ref{math:f1}.

\restoreequations
Our formula:
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = 2x \label{math:f2}
\end{equation}
See equation \ref{math:f2}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the purpose is, but…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \robert_suppress_equation:N
 {
  \regex_match:nVTF { \c{label} } #1
   { \__robert_suppress_text:N #1 }
   { \textbf{Equation~suppressed} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__robert_suppress_text:N
 {
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { \A .* \c{label}( \cB..*?\cE. ) .* \Z }
   { \c{__robert_suppress:n}\1 }
   #1
   % Print 
   #1
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \robert_equation: \equation
\cs_set_eq:NN \robert_endequation: \endequation
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__robert_suppress:n
 {
  \textbf{Equation~(\ref{#1})~suppressed}\label{#1}
 }

\RenewEnviron{equation}
 {
  \robert_equation:
  \robert_suppress_equation:N \BODY
  \robert_endequation:
 }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This equation has a \verb|\label|
\begin{equation}
A+B=0 \label{first}
\end{equation}
but this one hasn't
\begin{equation}
x=1
\end{equation}
That's all, but we had equation~\ref{first}
at page~\pageref{first}.

\end{document}
```

[image]